# returning blank json data while accesing album in facebook

Tags: android, facebook

When i am using Graph API of facebook in android ( with facebook android sdk )
to access albums m  using following url

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

but unfortunately it is returning {"data":[]}

other urls like

```
  https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

are working totally fine.

so i don't know for what reason its returning {"data":[]}. I tried accessing my own account on facebook and use example url provided on Graph API & over there if i use following url then its giving me all necessary data. but not working in facebook android sdk

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The photo albums this user has
>   created. Requires the user_photos or
>   friend_photos permission

You need that permission!

Comment: Already assigned user_photos permission. I cannot find friend_photos permission from the list here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions